# How can i implement debounced auto save on input change in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, react-hooks, debouncing

So the problem is lets say you have an editor.
The user keeps typing in the editor and he idles for a while like 5 seconds. So after idling for 5 seconds, you made a network request to the api to save what he typed in the database. It should make only one request after 5 seconds of idling.

I got it done but it made the requests which is equal to the amount of words. if you  type like `asdf` , it made four api request. In my example, four `console.log()`;

```
const EditorComponent = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  // I need another logic which checks the time difference of idling.

  const debounced = () => {
    return debounce(() => {
      console.log("the api is going to call after 5 seconds");
    }, 5000);
  };

  const onEditorStateChange = value => {
    const rawContent = convertToRaw(value.getCurrentContent());
    const markdown = draftToMarkdown(rawContent);
    setEditorState(value);
    debounced()
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "500px" }}>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
        wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
        editorClassName="editorClassName"
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditorComponent;
```

Comment: try 
const debounced = debounce(() => {
      console.log("the api is going to call after 5 seconds");
    }, 5000);
  };

Comment: @VivekN Dude, that's exactly what i did. Or am i missing something ?

Comment: Observe the code he wrote, he immediately executed the debounce instead of putting inside a function, what you are doing here is you are creating a new debounce function, everytime you are calling debounced method, debounce(function) gives a function which you can use inside onEditorStateChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that a new debounced function is created on every render and hence the APIs are being called multiple times. You must use `useCallback` to memoize the debounced function. If you want to use `editorState` within the debounced function, you can pass it on from `onEditStateChange` method when you call `debounced` . Also you need to correct your debounce syntax

```
const EditorComponent = () => {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  // I need another logic that checks the time difference of idling.

  const debounced = useCallback(debounce(() => {
      console.log("the api is going to call after 5 seconds");
  }, 5000), []);

  const onEditorStateChange = value => {
    const rawContent = convertToRaw(value.getCurrentContent());
    const markdown = draftToMarkdown(rawContent);
    setEditorState(value);
    debounced()
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ width: "500px" }}>
      <Editor
        editorState={editorState}
        toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
        wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
        editorClassName="editorClassName"
        onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditorComponent;
```

Comment: I'm almost sure that `debounced()` will send `editorState` to API. so `editorState` should be set as dependency for `useCallback`, otherwise `debounced` will point to outdated value through its closure.

Comment: @skyboyer, that is why I mentioned that we must pass on the editorState  to debounced function from onEditorStatechange method instead of relying on its closure otherwise  there won't be any benefit of useCallback

Comment: yes, sure, passing `editorState` through arguments works too.but why do you think closure removes benefits of using `useCallback`?

Comment: @skyboyer, if the editor state changes, the callback function is created again, which was the original case.

Comment: yes, you are right, I'm wrong. maybe is it better to move `const debounced = ...` outside of component then?